# Pandas pivot table to transpose multiple rows into column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe structured like this:

```
+---------------+---------------------------+--------+
|     Email     |          Paid at          |  Name  |
+---------------+---------------------------+--------+
| john@mail.com | 2019-11-20 12:23:06 +0100 | #10710 |
| ed@mail.com   | 2019-11-20 11:36:24 +0100 | #10709 |
| john@mail.com | 2019-11-19 14:58:41 +0100 | #10700 |
| ed@mail.com   | 2019-11-19 14:41:30 +0100 | #10699 |
| dev@mail.com  | 2019-11-19 14:20:26 +0100 | #10697 |
+---------------+---------------------------+--------+
```

And my final goal is to aggregate all the transactions made by one user, in a format like this one:

```
+---------------+---------------------------+--------+---------------------------+--------+--+
|     Email     |          Paid at          |  Name  |          Paid at          |  Name  |  |
+---------------+---------------------------+--------+---------------------------+--------+--+
| john@mail.com | 2019-11-20 12:23:06 +0100 | #10710 | 2019-11-19 14:58:41 +0100 | #10700 |  |
| ed@mail.com   | 2019-11-20 11:36:24 +0100 | #10709 | 2019-11-19 14:41:30 +0100 | #10699 |  |
| dev@mail.com  | 2019-11-19 14:20:26 +0100 | #10697 |                           |        |  |
+---------------+---------------------------+--------+---------------------------+--------+--+
```

My starting dataframe has been constructed like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Email':['john@mail.com', 'ed@mail.com', 
                       'john@mail.com', 'ed@mail.com', 'dev@mail.com'],
             'Paid at':['2019-11-20 12:23:06 +0100', 
                        '2019-11-20 11:36:24 +0100', 
                        '2019-11-19 14:58:41 +0100', 
                        '2019-11-19 14:41:30 +0100',
                       '2019-11-19 14:20:26 +0100'],
             'Name':['#10710', '#10709', '#10700', '#10699', '#10697']})
```

I have tried using the pivot functions `df.pivot(index='Email', columns='Name', values='Paid at')` and I can get a dataframe for which every timestamp is a column and the index in the email, but I am stuck in understanding how I can create the columns I want.

Comment: Mark link Q10 .

Comment: @WeNYoBen still a duplicate? You marked it as a duplicate of a question regarding pivot tables in pandas. The solution does not contain a pivot table at all. Why did you do this?

Comment: This still a dup , try to look at the whole link I shared, your question can be solved by q10 + q11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#convert column to datetimes
df['Paid at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Paid at'])
#descending sorting by datetimes
df = df.sort_values('Paid at', ascending=False)
#create MultiIndex by counter with cumcount, reshape by unstack, change order of columns
df = (df.set_index(['Email', df.groupby('Email', sort=False).cumcount()])
        .unstack()
        .sort_index(axis=1, level=[1,0], ascending=[True, False]))
#flatten MultIndex in columns
df.columns = df.columns.map('{0[0]}_{0[1]}'.format)
#convert index to column
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed a nice approach, however, it can happen that a transaction happens more than 2 times, so the final dataframe should also 'capture' this. How can it be modified?

Comment: @sanna - Not sure if understand, is possible create sample data for see it?

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame({'Email':['john@mail.com', 'ed@mail.com', 
                       'john@mail.com', 'ed@mail.com', 'dev@mail.com', 'ed@mail.com'],
             'Paid at':['2019-11-20 12:23:06 +0100', 
                        '2019-11-20 11:36:24 +0100', 
                        '2019-11-19 14:58:41 +0100', 
                        '2019-11-19 14:41:30 +0100',
                       '2019-11-19 14:20:26 +0100',
                           '2019-11-14 20:13:02 +0100'],
             'Name':['#10710', '#10709', '#10700', '#10699', '#10697', '#10623']})`

Comment: @sanna - What is expected output with new data?

Comment: In this case, Ed did 3 transactions, while John only two. How to create n columns (probably corresponding to the maximum number of transactions occurred per customer) so that if one user did 2 transactions only two columns will have dates, and if another user did four only four columns are filled.

Comment: I am creating a table for you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202976/discussion-between-sanna-and-jezrael).

Comment: @sanna - Super, I hope working nice my solution. Don't forget to accept the answer, if it suits you! :)